# Create New Column Based on Sub Identification Number

Tags: r

In one column I have both group IDs listed. An ID number followed by _01 indicates members in Group 1. An ID number followed by _02 indicates members in group 2.

I want to create a new column that will populate with 0's for the corresponding id_01 numbers and populate with 1's for the corresponding id_02 numbers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say this is your data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c("A_01", "A_02", "B_01", "B_02"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
df
#  ID
#1 A_01
#2 A_02
#3 B_01
#4 B_02
```

You can derive the new column something like this:

```
df$NewCol <- ifelse(grepl("_01", df$ID), 0, 1)
df
#  ID   NewCol
#1 A_01      0
#2 A_02      1
#3 B_01      0
#4 B_02      1
```

The `grepl` will search for the pattern in each row of `df$ID` and if's found it will put a 0, and if not it will put a 1.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried that and it make all the variables 1s. Two questions. Does it matter that it is formatted as "A-01", rather than "A_01"? Does it matter that the ID is a chr?

Comment: the ID will need to be a character, yes. Can you add your data (or a subset of your data using `dput(head(data))` ) to your question so we can test with it?

Comment: Amazing, that worked. Thank you so much! This was my first question on stack overflow.

Comment: No worries. Feel free to accept this as an answer if it has solved your problem

Comment: haha, it should just be a tick under the number of votes an answer has :P